# Passing a systemverilog class handle from a module to a class defined in a package

Tags: system-verilog

I have a SystemVerilog package file with a number of classes defined for specific network packet types used in our design. Each of these classes includes a task to build the packet in a small scratch buffer. The buffer is another class that includes a memory, an index, etc. The buffer class is defined in a header file and included in both the package file and in my testbench.

(Is this even the right way to do this? Maybe I've started off on the wrong foot to begin with!)

My plan was to create a single instance of the packet_buffer class in the testbench and pass its handle to each network packet classes build task as I create those packets. However, doing this Modelsim says the types are not "assignment compatible". One class is named tb::packet_buffer and the other is pkg_file::packet_buffer. The name of the module/package is attached to the class type so they don't look the same.

How do I pass a handle between the two?

Here's an example of what is in my testbench.

```
t_packet_buffer     pkt = new();          // Create scratch buffer
t_packet_custom     my_packet = new();    // Create specific custom network packet
.
.
.
my_packet.build_packet(pkt);             // Call "build_packet" and pass it the scratch buffer handle
```

My second thought was to build each packet class with its own buffer, but eventually I'd have to pass that back to the testbench so I'd have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the class definition in a package and then `import` the package into the testbench, do not `` `include `` the file. Otherwise you are creating two distinct types.

See https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2010/07/13/package-import-versus-include/